# What does defaultdict(list, {}) or dict({}) do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I saw this online and I'm confused on what the second argument would do:

`defaultdict(list, {})`

Looking at what I get on the console, it seems to simply create a `defaultdict` where values are lists by default. If so, is this exactly equivalent to running `defaultdict(list)`?

From I read online:

> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory attribute; it defaults to `None`. All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the `dict` constructor, including keyword arguments.

which also makes me wonder about the difference between:

- `my_dict = dict({})`
- `my_dict = dict()`

Comment: Yes, the results are equivalent.

Comment: The results are equivalent, it is needlessly passing an empty dict. Probably someone who isn't very familiar with Python

Answer (score 1):

`dict({...})` just makes a dict:

```
>>> dict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Which is equal to this:

```
>>> dict(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

or

```
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

The same applies for `defualtdict`.

Answer (score 1):

the argument to the dict class in python is the instantiation values.. so passing an {} creates an empty dictionary.

Its the same case with defaultdict, except that the first argument is the default type of the values for every key.